# AucTex C-c KEY-combo no longer works

Tags: auctex

**Solved:** I found another Emacs user who have had the same exact same issue. The solution is to remove the installed AucTex and reinstall it. This has fixed the issue.

I have changed my Emacs configuration and after I did this commands from AucTex, the font commands and other commands such as `C-[` doesn't work anymore, and I cannot figure out why.
As soon as I hit `C-c C-f` it attempts to compile the document.

The part of Configuration that concerns AucTex looks like this:

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (local-set-key [C-tab] 'TeX-complete-symbol)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

My full configuration is here

```
* Set up package repositories 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
#+END_SRC

** Installed Packages 

- Powerline 
- Flycheck 
- Flyspell
- Markdown mode
- AucTex 
- Move Text
- exec-path-from-shell-initialize
- markdown-mode 
- scss-mode
- web-beautify
- web-mode
- easy-jekyll 

* Set up general Emacs Configurations 

Here we do general global editor and UI configurations. 
We do the following: 

- Remove the scrol bar 
- Show matching parenthesis
- Remove the tool bar 
- Remove the menu bar 
- Remove the bell sound 
- Change how compleition is done when cycling through options 
- Delete old versions of files on save 
- Remove the startup message 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; remove scrollbar
(show-paren-mode 1) ;; show matching parenthesis
(tool-bar-mode -1) ;; Remove the toolbar in the top
(menu-bar-mode -1) ;; remove menue bar
(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore) ;; Removes the warning bell
;;; Customise some things that make emacs easier to use
(setq completion-cycle-threshold t) ;; Allows for auto complete to cycle through options 
(setq default-directory "~/") ;; Set the default place to look for files
(setq delete-old-versions t) ;; Remove old versions of files on save 
(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; Remove the start-up message from emacs
#+END_SRC

** Link files to specific modes when needed

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp 
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\wscript\\'" . python-mode))
#+END_SRC

* Mac Settings 

Here we setup custome keys and modifiers for keys on macOS. 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(when (string-equal system-type "darwin")
   (setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil)
   (setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
   (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
   (setq mac-option-modifier nil)
   (setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")
   (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin"))) ;; Path to brew executables
   (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
)
#+END_SRC


* Move Text 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'move-text)
(move-text-default-bindings)
#+END_SRC

* Org Mode configuration 

Loading Packages for need for my org-mode configuration. 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'ox-latex)
#+END_SRC

** Modifying org-mode /Todo/ 

First, I change the /keywords/

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "DOING" "FEEDBACK" "VERIFY" "|" "DONE" "DELEGATED")))
#+END_SRC

I also need to be able to see when I finished a task. 
So I have to enable /log done/.

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq org-log-done t)
#+END_SRC

** Setup capture 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)
#+END_SRC



* Powerline 

Powerline provides better information than default bottom line in emacs 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'powerline)
(powerline-default-theme)
#+END_SRC 

* Setup spelling for fly spell 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

(require 'ispell)
#+END_SRC

** Setup the program used for spelling and set the dictionary

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
(setq ispell-dictionary "en_GB")
#+END_SRC

** Setup modes where it is auto loaded 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(add-hook 'c++-mode 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode) 
(add-hook 'org-mode 'flyspell-mode) 
(add-hook 'python-mode 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
#+END_SRC


* LaTeX and AucTex


#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;;(require 'auctex)

(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (local-set-key [C-tab] 'TeX-complete-symbol)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
#+END_SRC

* Magit Settings 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp 
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g s") 'magit-status)
#+END_SRC

* Language Server Setup 

TBW

* Easy Jekyll setup 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq easy-jekyll-basedir "~/Dev/embras/embras-website/")
#+END_SRC
```

I cannot spot what should have caused this to happen.

Comment: What is `C-c` bound to?  Do `C-h k C-c` to find out.

Comment: It may be `C-c C-f` that is the issue, I get this: `C-c C-f runs the command tex-file (found in plain-tex-mode-map), which`

Comment: Hmm.  Is auctex LaTeX-mode actually loaded?  In the offending buffer, do `C-h v major-mode`

Comment: Yeah it is loaded.

Comment: A friend had experienced the same. He asked me to remove the installed auctex and install it again. That seems to have fixed it